# Fazer elemento sumir conforme a data do sistema

Tags: jquery

Tenho varias 'boxes' com datas no html, exemplo:

```
<div id="agenda">
  <a href="javascript:void" class="web-thumb">
     <span class="data">13 set</span>
     <span class="hora">10h30</span>
     <p class="tema green-sage">eSocial</p>
  </a>
  <a href="javascript:void" class="web-thumb">
     <span class="data">13 set</span>
     <span class="hora">14h</span>
     <p class="tema green-sage">eSocial</p>
  </a>
  <a href="javascript:void" class="web-thumb">
    <span class="data">14 set</span>
    <span class="hora">10h30</span>
    <p class="tema green-sage">eSocial</p>
  </a>            
</div>
```

Eu preciso que via jQuery as 'boxes' com data inferiores ao sistema desapareçam.

Comment: Data inferior, que você diz, é a data atual?

Comment: A data inferior é a que é exibida dentro do <span class="data">

Comment: Sim, mas eu vou comparar ela com qual outra data, exatamente? A data atual?

Comment: Isso mesmo! a data atual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), e jQuery, isto fica bem simples.

```
$("a.web-thumb").each(function() {
    var data_atual = moment();
    var data_teste = moment("13/09/2016", "dd/MM/yyyy"); // Aqui eu coloquei fixo, mas você 
                                                         // pode usar, por exemplo, 
                                                         // $(this).find("span.data").text(), 
                                                         // mas no formato "13/09/2016", e não 
                                                         // "13 set", como na pergunta.
    if (data_teste.diff(data_atual) < 0) 
    {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Coloque este evento em `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`.

Comment: Muito obrigado Cigano!

Comment: @MunirBaarini [Veja aqui como funciona o site](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Obrigado!